# Endeca Thesaurus & Keyword Redirect Issues

Tags: redirect, keyword, endeca, thesaurus

We are having some trouble with Endeca workbench entries for the thesaurus.

There seems to be an issue with multiword --> multiword one way mappings.

> rubber wheels --> rubber tyres

There also seems to be an issue with entries including characters like '-' & '.'. I altered the config using the Endeca developer studio to use these special search characters to no avail.

> f.r.u.i.t. --> fruit
>
> bb-es71 --> bb71

Search results are not returning results for the mapped thesaurus entries. Other appear to work as expected and the special characters have definitely been added to the search_chars.xml config file.

As well as this we are seeing odd behaviour in the keyword redirects where both 'lube' & 'cube' have separate entries but searching for lube redirects to the cube url. Same issue for lock & look. Could this be to do with the match mode. It's currently set to matchallpartial.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Current system is using:

- CAS 3.0.1 (Content Acquisition System)
- MDEX 6.2.2
- PlatformServices 6.1.2
- PresentationAPI 6.1.4
- Workbench 2.1.2
- Content Assembler API 2.1.2

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues with `one way` `multi word` thesaurus entries. Did you `promote content` after editing the thesaurus? Have you tried to debug it using the Endeca Reference Application?

Comment: @radimpe Debugging via the reference app simply gives no results. I have resolved the other issues though. The redirect issue was an error in application logic caused by using multiple search interfaces. The special chars issue was caused by missing config. I still can't get multiword thesaurus entries to map though. By promote content do you mean push to production?

Comment: If I am not wrong, thesaurus entries will just affect the Authoring Dgraph unless you run the promote content script, like radimpe said, in order to see the changes in the live Dgraph.

Answer (score 0):

as per your example

rubber wheels --> rubber tyres. If you search for rubber wheels, Endeca will apply thesaurus for a string like "...rubber tyres..." but not for "..rubber....tyres".

As per Endeca documentation below :-
Multi-word equivalences are matched on a phrase basis. For example, if a thesaurus equivalence between wine opener and corkscrew is defined, then a search for corkscrew will match the text stainless steel wine opener, but will not match the text an effective opener for wine casks.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Ajay Agrawal